# Is there a word for a pie chart that is in the shape of a rectangle?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

Normally, pie charts are circular and each piece of data is shown as a slice of a whole.

However, for some purposes, it makes more sense to display the same kind of data as a rectangle divided up with vertical lines, with each horizontal "slice" of the rectangle representing a piece of the data.

It would look like **one** rectangle cut into multiple slices along **one** dimension. For example, suppose my data was different types of transportation used in the United States, and the data was the following, then the plot might look like the ASCII depiction below the data.

```
Bicycle,25%
Plane,25%
Car,50%


________________________________________________
|_Bicycle__|____Plane___|_________Car___________|
```

Note that the intent of the above depiction is to have one long rectangle cut into 3 pieces. Two are `25%` of the total rectangle and one is `50%` of the rectangle.

Is there a word for this kind of "rectangular" pie chart?

Comment: I'd suggest "terminology" as a more relevant tag than "diction", and also include the "single-word-request" tag, that ought to grab people's attention.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Edited the tags. Thanks!

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Comment: _Detroit-style pizza chart_, perhaps? ;-)

Comment: http://annkemery.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/diverging_before-after1.jpg This is the type of chart you're after. And here's another link http://excelforeducators.blogspot.it/2011/10/how-stacked-bars-stack-up.html

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Yes, that looks like it!

Comment: A "100% stacked bar" chart is probably the closest you will find.

Comment: Brownie Chart?...

Comment: I think it is called a divided bar chart

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking about is a *bar chart* or *bar graph* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart ).

**Update:**

In one of the comments above, Jesse suggested *stacked bar chart*. Googling for corresponding images results in a great number of exactly the type of chart you are asking about being displayed.

**Second update:**

Just for the sake of completeness, I've reinstated a link that someone posted (and then deleted) to the following Wikipedia description of a further type of rectangular chart:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping

Comment: No, I am not looking for a bar chart. I think I described it poorly.

Comment: See the updated question.

Comment: In this case, since merlin2011 seems to be more interested in showing the _proportions_ of the parts than representing them in a _quantitative_ way, a specific type of stacked bar chart would usually be used. In most data visualisation applications, this type of chart will be referred to as a "100% stacked bar [column] chart". This could include more than one bar (to show transport type by age groups, for example), but there is no necessity for this, it can be applied to a single segmented bar just the same.

Comment: A stacked bar chart of percentages would always have the same width.

Comment: Treepmap was the thing I looked for :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a kind of bar chart...

Comment: This comes closer to the image of the idea I am looking for, but the idea is to have a rectangle cut into literal slices along one dimension, where each slice is proportional to the size of the data point.

Comment: @merlin2011 -- Could you post a link to the kind of chart you are asking about? I think we need to see an example.

Comment: So you are looking for a bar chart with only one bar, something like that?

Comment: @ErikKowal, It is extremely hard to find a picture without the word. I have only seen such pictures in other people's presentations. I just made a simple ascii depiction in my question.

Comment: @user2860952, I am looking for a single rectangle, chopped into slices based on the proportion of each category, the same way a pie chart is a circle is chopped into slices based on the proportion of each category.

Comment: Your previous answer was more useful, it had a link and I for one, would not have known what treemapping looked like. You can always add your second comment to the original edit to acknowledge the OP's clarifications.

Comment: Maybe `stacked bar chart` is the key word to search.

Comment: Please @jesse post your answer. I have found this link and it fits http://excelforeducators.blogspot.it/2011/10/how-stacked-bars-stack-up.html, also thanks to Erik Kowal's edit.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- It is very nice of you. Your effort searching for the answer desrves a post, not mine.

Comment: @jesse post it! YOU are the one who deserves recognition. I would never have looked if it hadn't been for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are types of [heat maps](https://www.google.com/search?q=rectangle%20heat%20map%20chart&client=firefox-a&hs=AQJ&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=sb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=A-xpU8SSCujQyAG1qoGoBQ&ved=0CDIQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=928) that are rectangle and function like pie charts.  Depending on your needs there is probably a variation that will work for you.